# Redirect unauthorized users to custom login view [Asp.net Core 5]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5, asp.net5

I use `Identity` in an `Asp.net Core 5` project targeted `.Net 5`.
As you know when make a `Controller` as `Authorize` any user try to access any `view` in the controller the `Identity` will redirect him to the `/Identity/Account/Login` razor page, so I created my own login controller with views.

**The question:**
I wanna the `unauthorized` users to redirected to my custom `login` view, how can I do that ?

**What I tried:**
In `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class I added this piece of code :

```
        services.AddAuthentication( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme )
                .AddCookie( options =>
                            {
                                options.LoginPath = "/Login";

                            } );

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

But still not working the users still redirected to `/Identity/Account/Login` and I wanna them riderected to my custom `login view`.

Comment: Use the `ConfigureApplicationCookie()` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.configureapplicationcookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Massive thanks bro it works <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ASP.NET Core, where do you configure redirect to login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011114/in-asp-net-core-where-do-you-configure-redirect-to-login)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I replaced my old code with :

```
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie( options =>
                                         {
                                             options.LoginPath = "/Login";

                                         } );
```

Thanks to [Martin Costello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064169/martin-costello)